# Does the use of quantized data help make matrix computations faster?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Given a quantized dataset $\mathcal{D}$ of $N$-dimensional data ; where only certain values are permitted for each vector component (for example $\mathcal{D} \subset \{1,2,3,4,5\}^N$), could this knowledge be used to speed-up matrix/vector operations which map any data point $x$ from $\mathcal{D}$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$  ($f : \{1,2,3,4,5\}^N \mapsto \mathbb{R}^N $) ?

Comment: Yes it could. For example if D is small you could pre calculate tables for operations between D and D or build the constants into hardware.

Comment: If there are only a finite number of possible values, certainly - in the extreme, you could forgo any sort of calculative function and just implement a lookup table if memory isn't a concern. Even if not (say, $\mathcal{D}\subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$) having more knowledge about your input cannot make your calculation more complicated.